# django form field displayed out of order

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I have this form and model for a group:

```
class GroupForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = ('leader', 'description', 'size', 'max_size', 'motto')

        widgets = {
            'size': forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={'id': 'size'}),
            'max_size': forms.TextInput(attrs={'type': 'hidden', 'id': 'maxSize'}),
        }
```

The creator of the group has an option to check yes for `size` and on doing so, I used javascript to change the type of `max_size` to `show`.

In my `create_group.html` template:

```
<script>
    let size = document.getElementById('size')
    let maxSize = document.getElementById('maxSize')
    let checked = false
    
    size.onclick = () => {
        checked = !checked
        if (checked === true) {
            maxSize.type = 'show'
        } else {
            maxSize.type = 'hidden'
        }
        
    }
</script>
```

Now, this works fine, the only problem is that the fields are displayed out of order.

When the page loads, `max_size` is `false` and its field is not displayed. Which is good. However, when the user checks that group has a size, and, subsequently, the `max_size` has a display of `show`, the field shows up after the motto field and not in its correct order according to `fields = ('leader', 'description', 'size', 'max_size', 'motto')`.

Furthermore, the `max_size` field is included inside the `motto` element itself and not as its own field:

[image]

vs. the other fields which are all in their own `<p></p>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else comes across this issue, it's also possible to just use js and css. Right now, I'm using javascript to see if `size` is checked and if it is then `maxSize.style.display = 'block'` vs `maxSize.style.display = 'none'` if `size` isn't checked.

Then I had the issue of django's form label still being visible. To fix that I saw an answer on [dev.to](https://dev.to/greenteabiscuit/deleting-the-form-field-label-in-django-1i20) which you can see for yourself.

My issue now is that I don't know how to add a label that is only visible when the form field is visible.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that `{{form.as_p}}` etc. render all the visible fields first, then the hidden ones.

You can explicitly render the fields in the order you want in your template. Rather than hardcoding the order in your template, maybe this (I've never tried this):

```
FIELD_ORDER = ( ('leader', 'description', 'size', 'max_size', 'motto')
class GroupForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = FIELD_ORDER
```

Pass to your template a list of fields explicitly in the order you want:

```
fields_in_order = [ form[x] for x in FIELD_ORDER ]
```

In the template

```
{% for field in fields_in_order %}
   {{field}}
{% endfor %}
```

Or, you can make the hiding of this field something done by JS

Comment: the hiding of the field is already done through JS though.

Comment: also what do you mean by 'pass to your template...' Like, where does this line go: fields_in_order = [ form[x] for x in FIELD_ORDER ]

Comment: Wherever ... if you are using Class-Based Views, "pass to template" means put it in the context in get_context_data. So, in there, `context['fields_in_order'] = [ form[x] for ...]` (you may need to retrieve `form=context['form']` assuming you called the superclass first)